# Installing and Running MongoDB - Many Errors on Mac

Tags: mongodb, macos, homebrew

I'm trying to install mongoDB on my Mac. However, I'm running into a lot of issues.

I first installed mongoDB using Homebrew by running the following commands:

```
brew tap mongodb/brew

brew install mongodb-community@4.2
```

Then ran it using:

```
brew services start mongodb-community@4.2
```

Everything looks fine at this point, until I try running in the terminal:

```
mongod
```

At first I thought the issue was that I didn't create the /data/db folder, so I ran:

```
sudo mkdir -p /data/db
```

This did not work.

I then found an article stating Mac users need to run:

```
sudo mkdir -p /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

This worked.. then I ran:

```
mongod --dbpath /System/Volumes/Data/data/db
```

And received the following:

```
2020-02-09T20:36:07.667-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=65406 port=27017 dbpath=/System/Volumes/Data/data/db 64-bit host=user-MacBook-Pro.local
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:36:07.672-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { storage: { dbPath: "/System/Volumes/Data/data/db" } }
2020-02-09T20:36:07.673-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2020-02-09T20:36:07.673-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-09T20:36:07.673-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

I tried running:

```
sudo chown -Rv user /System/Volumes/Data/data/db

mongod
```

Then received the following:

```
2020-02-09T20:36:52.247-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=65410 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=user-MacBook-Pro.local
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:36:52.249-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-02-09T20:36:52.250-0500 E  STORAGE  [initandlisten] Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
2020-02-09T20:36:52.250-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-09T20:36:52.250-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:48
```

For the SocketException, I tried:

```
mongod --port 27018
```

And received:

```
2020-02-09T20:37:39.191-0500 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=65414 port=27018 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=user-MacBook-Pro.local
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.3
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 6874650b362138df74be53d366bbefc321ea32d4
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-02-09T20:37:39.195-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: { net: { port: 27018 } }
2020-02-09T20:37:39.196-0500 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found., terminating
2020-02-09T20:37:39.196-0500 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-02-09T20:37:39.196-0500 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-02-09T20:37:39.196-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-02-09T20:37:39.196-0500 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I just can't seem to figure out what's going on, since I've just been following all the steps I've found on StackOverflow from other people with this exact issue.

Comment: I am not familiar with homebrew software. I think you are trying many things and some are working and some are not working (it is not clear what is and not). MongoDB database requires _one successful installation_ and _one successful start_. Once it is started successfully it can be _accessed_ using tools like Mongo Shell or MongoDB Compass. Here are [general instructions on installing. starting and accessing MOngoDB on MacOS](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/index.html).

Comment: also not familiar with brew but it sounds like once you run `brew services start` it would have already started the 'mongod' and that's why when attempting to run it again it says "Address already in use". instead just connect to the already running instance with "mongo" or compass at the default address. in a terminal try running "mongo" and it should connect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some more research and viewing the comments above, it appears that when installing MongoDB through homebrew you will use the following commands:

```
brew services start mongodb-community
```

Then in a new tab:

```
mongo
```

This will start mongo successfully. I'm still not 100% sure why `mongod` kicks back errors, but for all I know, the above works.

Comment: `mongod` kicks back errors because it's already started with `brew services ...`. It says in log: `Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use`.